# ssl certificate issue on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ssl, nginx

I have an aws ec2 server with ubuntu 14.04 and nginx setup. Both frontend and backend(nodejs) are on same server. I have separate nginx file for both  and are working fine on http.

I need to add ssl certificate on both ends. Let say Frontend is on `xyz.co` and backend is on `api.xyz.co`.

For Frontend i have used lets encrypt ssl certificate and on port 443 its working perfectly. I have used this link :

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04

Problem:

The issue is, when i go and add a `self signed` certificate on nginx for backend rather than using lets encrypt certificate, i am not able to get it running.

Here is my backend nginx config.

https://gist.github.com/dg92/7d6030a8ab54f2d4184104b34edd5c41

Need Help.

Comment: are you _proxying_ to `api.xyz.co`?

Comment: Also remember to optimise your ssl nginx configs like [this](https://medium.com/@mvuksano/how-to-properly-configure-your-nginx-for-tls-564651438fe0#.z8drubfej)

Comment: yes proxy is used

Comment: you do not really need to setup certs then!

Comment: Please explain in details. My frontend is https now so every api call should be https so for that i am doing so. let me know if i am wrong.

Comment: can you run `nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t` and tell me the output

Comment: nginx.conf is not my file where i did this. I made a file in site-available api.xyz.co

Comment: it `includes` the files where you did

Comment: as of now its giving test failed, ```[emerg] 20320#0: "upstream" directive is not allowed here```

Comment: can you send me your `xyz.co` config

Comment: refer to this: https://gist.github.com/dg92/fb24583e51cc15c69169f6174bc31138

Comment: where is the ssl config?

Comment: Please check the link. gist.github.com/dg92/fb24583e51cc15c69169f6174bc31138

Comment: @Maximilian Did you find anything ?

Comment: Can you send me more of that error message? `[emerg] 20320#0: "upstream" directive is not allowed here`

Comment: it was just that error that i send you. Nothing more.

Comment: Output of `grep -rnw '/etc/nginx/' -e "upstream"`

Comment: ```/etc/nginx/sites-available/api.xyz.co:1:upstream api_upstream {
Binary file /etc/nginx/sites-available/.api.xyz.co.swp matches```

Comment: @Maximilian any light on this ?

Comment: How are you defining working perfectly?

Comment: @Maximilian when i go and type ```https://xyz.co``` on browser its working but my backend apis are on http, so they need to be on https also so that they work.
For this reason i need to make my sub domain ```api.xyz.co``` to ```https://api.xyz.co```.
By the way all routes are on https i.e ```https://localhost:3000``` is working.

so my only need is to make ```https://api.xyz.co``` to work and then proxy pass is to ```https://localhost:3000```

Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

I was an issue with my nginx, uninstalled and reinstalled again and it worked.